What kind of weatherstipping do I need for my entry door?
I'm having trouble figuring out what to use to weatherseal my exterior door.
I've had cold leaks come in because the last weatherstrip was torn in some places. I wasn't there for the last installation so I don't know what kind of strip it was, as you can see (pic 3) it is very used so it's harder for me to know what it looks like brand new.
When I removed the older strip, it felt like it wasnt the push in types, I was ripping it from the frame. With pic 1 it looks like it was part of a bigger part that clipped in the door frame (is that a thing, pic. 4?), but I can't find anything like that in retail stores.
I've been suggested the product in pic 2 but Its not the same strip and I can't find anything resembling the last one.
I added a cheap stick-on foam seal to temporarily help.




